# Adding generated PDF to FileField fails; adding local PDF works

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generate a PDF file and to add it to a Django `FileField`. Nothing fancy, but I can't seem to get i

When using a local file on my hard drive, everything works fine:

```
>>> invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=153)
>>> local_file = open('my.pdf')
>>> djangofile = File(local_file)
>>> type(local_file)
<type 'file'>
>>> type(djangofile)
<class 'django.core.files.base.File'>
>>> invoice.pdf = djangofile
>>> invoice.pdf
<FieldFile: my.pdf>
>>> invoice.save()
>>> invoice.pdf
<FieldFile: documents/invoices/2016/07/my.pdf>
```

However when trying the same with a generated PDF, things don't work:

```
>>> invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=154)
>>> html_template = get_template('invoicing/invoice_pdf.html')
>>> rendered_html = html_template.render({'invoice': invoice}).encode(encoding="UTF-8")
>>> pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html).write_pdf()
>>> type(pdf_file)
<type 'str'>
>>> djangofile = File(pdf_file)
>>> type(djangofile)
<class 'django.core.files.base.File'>
>>> invoice.pdf = djangofile
>>> invoice.pdf
<FieldFile: None>
>>> invoice.save()
>>> invoice.pdf
<FieldFile: None>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is one `django.core.files.base.File` object accepted and another one isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File()` is only a wrapper around Python's file object. It won't work with strings like your generated PDF. For that, you need the [ContentFile class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class). Try:

```
(...)
djangofile = ContentFile(pdf_file)
invoice.pdf = djangofile
invoice.pdf.name = "myfilename.pdf"
invoice.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. What is missing is that I also needed to provide a filename for storage through `invoice.pdf.name`, or no actual `save()` occurs. I've adjusted your answer.